# I found this bug on my washer please help identify it

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]The bug was a light brown
It had like 4 legs and two antennas

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! For identification questions please [edit] your post to include the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this creature. The location can be an essential clue for identifications. ——— If possible clear, closeup photos of the creature from multiple angles would also be helpful. ——— Please see the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site as well as clicking on the species-identification tag for details. Thanks!

Comment: I live in northwestern Pennsylvania and I only got on picture but haven’t seen any more of them and oh boy I have been looking